# How to pass a pointer to a struct declared inside another struct as a function parameter?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, parameters

In one of my applications written in C I have a struct declared as a member of another struct:

```
struct _test
{
    int varA;
    //...

    struct _small
    {
        int varB;
        //...
    } small;
} test;
```

Now I want to create a function that access `varB` above, but I don't want it to access the entire structure `test`, that is, I don't want to do:

```
#include <relevant_header>

void myFunction()
{
    test.small.varB = 0;
}
```

instead, I want to pass only the `small` structure as a parameter to that function; something like this:

```
#include <relevant_header>

void myFunction(struct _test::_small* poSmall)
{
    poSmall->varB = 0;
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to do this, that is, the above code doesn't compile right (I suppose it's C++ syntax only). So how may I do this in a C code - pass a pointer to a struct that was declared inside another struct? I wasn't able to find anything about this both in SO as well as in Google in general.

Comment: `::` is a syntax error in C.  Just use `struct _small` to use a variable of type `struct _small`.  There's no scoping of nested structures in C like there is in C++.  And be wary of using names starting with an underscore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do:

```
void myFunction(struct _small *poSmall)
{
    poSmall->varB = 0;
}
```

The scope of `struct _small` is not limited to its outer structure.

Comment: first, thanks for the reply. But I don't think your suggestion is 100% acceptable: I did test it before posting the question and I considered it wrong because when I do this, the development platform (Qt Creator) doesn't recognize any more the items inside the struct. IOW, when I type `poSmall->` a box doesn't appear telling the variable options - while when using the scope that gives compiler errors, the box options appear. Isn't there any other way or I'll have to stick with some kind of Qt Creator's limitation? :T

Comment: @Momergil: What language is Qt using?  If it is C, ouah's answer is correct.  If it is not C, then the tag on the question is incorrect and it's anyone's guess as to what's appropriate.  If what ouah shows does not work for you, whatever you're using is not supporting standard C.

Comment: @Momergil are you sure you set your development tool in C mode?

Comment: @ouah AFAIK there is no such thing to do in Qt Creator; even when you create a whole new C project inside it, it makes no actual change in configuration. The closest thing I got when it comes to this was a link telling to add `QMAKE_CXX = gcc` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -x c` to the `.pro` configuration file, but after doing it nothing changed.